# Is Angular2 responsive out of the box?

Tags: angular

I've just started learning about Angular2 and I see a lot of people talking about how great it is. So this question just popped in my mind because I've started creating an application with Angular2 and I will be making it responsive at some point.

I know we can make a website responsive by using CSS framework 'Twitter bootstrap', but do I really need bootstrap or Angular2 handles the 'responsive-ness' out of the box?

Comment: do u know what is **css** and what is **javascript**??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is not a layouting framework its a client side single page application development MVC framework.

So the answer is NO.

The other point is you can simply use HTML and CSS for making responsive applications for eg. media query.

Answer (score 1):

For the layout and responsiveness you need styling and for that here are the options.

1. Your own custom CSS
2. Material Design
3. Material Design Lite (simpler version of material design).
4. materializecss.com (a more simplified version of material design).
5. Material Design Lite in combination with Twitter Bootstrap.

This site (http://www.thevisualized.com/) follows the fifth option. I believe it looks cool, responsive and yet so simply clean.

[image]

Here you go, a [website](http://www.thevisualized.com/) that visualize (initially for) Twitter and changes the way we follow hashtags and user handle via plotting their tweets. Thus, one can find the most liked/re-tweeted tweet or simply a pattern/trend on one's timeline. For what have been appreciated from the audience, visually.

Technology Stack

- Angular 2
- Node.js
- Express
- Material Lite Design
- Twitter Bootstrap
- Twitter API
- And supports server-side (using Angular Universal) rendering for SEO

This description of the [Web App](http://www.thevisualized.com/) answers your other concern regarding Angular2. I would recommend you to go for Angular 2. 
Give it a try, Good luck and Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

> do I really need bootstrap or Angular2 handles the 'responsive-ness'
>   out of the box?

Absolutely No. Angular is just a framework, it has nothing to do with CSS or responsive stuff.